# Show that $\mathbb P$ is finitly additive and that $\mathcal A$ is an algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given $\mathcal F=\{A \subset\Omega \mid A \mbox{ or } A^c \mbox{ is finite}\}$, show that $\mathcal F$ is an algebra.

Second, set:

$\mathbb P(A) = \begin{cases} 0, & \mbox{if } A \mbox{ is finite} \\ 1, & \mbox{if } A^c \mbox{ is finite} \end{cases}$

Show that $\mathbb P$ is finitely additive but not countably additive measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$.

I have not taken any course in measure theory but still, the probability course of course requires that I know this vaguely. Anyone can help?

Comment: Let's start with the definition of "algebra." What properties must $F$ satisfy?

Comment: That $\Omega \in F$, well it is since $A \cup A^c = \Omega$ right...?

Comment: Showing that $\Omega \in F$ is the first condition; but you don't yet know that $\Omega$ is closed under unions, right? But do you see why one of $\Omega$ and $\Omega^c$ is finite?

Comment: Ok how can I know that $\Omega$ is in $F$ since A is a SUBSET of $\Omega$. No, I don't see why one of them is finite.... :/

Comment: $\Omega$ is certainly a subset of itself. And $\Omega^c = \emptyset$, so....

Comment: Well if A is finite thus needs $A^c$ be finite and since $A\cup A^c=\Omega$ thus must $\Omega \cup \Omega^c$ be finite..

Comment: There's no reason to conclude that $A^c$ is finite; the point is that $\Omega$ has finite complement, and so must lie in $F$.

Comment: $\Omega^c$ must be finite since the definition says that either A or A complement is finite. I conclude this means that they are closed under unions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar situation. Consider $G=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x^2+x=6\}$. How would you check that $\color{red}{\bf42}$ belongs to $G$ or that $\color{red}{\bf42}$ does not belong to $G$? You would have to determine whether $\color{red}{\bf42}$ satisfies the defining property of $G$ or not. To be in $G$, one must be a real number (and $\color{red}{\bf42}$ is) and one must solve the identity $x^2+x=6$ (and $\color{red}{\bf42}$ does not, since $\color{red}{\bf42}^2+\color{red}{\bf42}=1706\ne6$). Conclusion: $\color{red}{\bf42}$ is not in $G$. Likewise, is $\color{green}{\bf2}$ in $G$? Check: $\color{green}{\bf2}$ is a real number and $\color{green}{\bf2}$ solves $x^2+x=6$ (since $\color{green}{\bf2}^2+\color{green}{\bf2}=6$), hence $\color{green}{\bf2}$ is in $G$.

Back to your problem. Users in the comments suggested that you first check that $\color{purple}{\bf\Omega}$ belongs to $F=\{A\subseteq\Omega\mid A\ \text{or}\ A^c\ \text{is finite}\}$. How to check this? Just like before: to be in $F$, one must be a subset of $\Omega$ (so you have to determine whether $\color{purple}{\bf\Omega}$ is a subset of $\Omega$ or not) and one must be finite or have a finite complement (so you have to determine if at least one of the sets $\color{purple}{\bf\Omega}$ or $\color{purple}{\bf\Omega}^c$ is finite, or not).

Your conclusion? Is $\color{purple}{\bf\Omega}$ in $F$ or not?